# Why doesn't NDepend produce a stable LOC count?

Tags: c#, static-analysis, ndepend, lines-of-code

I am using the NDepend 4.1 API to count the lines of code in a Visual Studio 2010 solution that has a few projects, which are all targeting the .NET Framework 4. Here's my code:

```
var servicesProvider = new NDependServicesProvider();
var projectManager = servicesProvider.ProjectManager;
var project = projectManager.CreateTemporaryProject( ... );
var analysisResult = project.RunAnalysis();

var methods = analysisResult.CodeBase.Application.Methods;
var totalLoc = methods.Where( i => i.NbLinesOfCode.HasValue ).Sum( i => i.NbLinesOfCode.Value );
```

If I repeatedly run this analysis on my solution, I get different results for `totalLoc` even though *I have not changed the solution or its compiled assemblies in any way.* For example, if I run the analysis three times, I might get `totalLoc` values of 12100, 12220, and 12075.

Digging a little deeper, I've started iterating through `analysisResult.CodeBase.Application.Methods` and writing each method's name and `NbLinesOfCode` to a text file. When I diff the files from any two analysis runs, I notice that most methods show a consistent LOC count but there are a handful that don't. I can't see any pattern in this and it doesn't seem to be the same set of methods each time.

What could be causing this strange behavior?

**Update 1:** If I run the analysis on any *single* assembly, I get a consistent LOC count. The problem only happens when I pass multiple assemblies to `CreateTemporaryProject`.

Comment: Debug vs Release builds?

Comment: @AustinSalonen: When I call `CreateTemporaryProject`, I am careful to always pass in exactly the same list of assemblies, which happen to be Debug assemblies right now.

Comment: The assemblies are not recompiled in between two analysis?

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam: That is correct. They are not being recompiled. I am calling `CreateTemporaryProject` with one class library assembly and two web assemblies. I verified that the last modified dates on these assemblies is not changing between analysis runs.

Comment: @William This is a pretty unexpected behavior, could you please send us the concerned assemblies at support at NOSPAM ndepend dot com?

Comment: Ok, to bypass this bug just

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug now fixed in [NDepend version 5](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependV5.aspx)!

Interestingly enough the bug came from a subtil concurrent access issue, that manifested with different analysis results when 2 large assemblies were analyzed on two different threads!